# Not sure which Stack Exchange site would be best for this type of question

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The question that I want to ask is about Tor, here is the question:

> I have the new alpha version of Tor (version 3.0). My goal is to have
>   Tor get a new identity using a Bash script. I have done this in the
>   past using a hashed password. Now I am trying to using a cookie file.
>   I have seen many examples of this but only work for older versions of
>   Tor.

So, should I ask this question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) because it is programming (but, I have the code), or should I ask this question on [Tor Stack Exchange](http://tor.stackexchange.com) because there could be something new in the new version of Tor?

Comment: Probably super user?

Comment: Why do you think SuperUser?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have too much to do with programming, so I'm inclined to agree about [su] or [tor.se] rather than [so]. That said, I'm not too knowledgeable in this domain.

Comment: Alright, I will try Super User.

Comment: I would ask on [Tor](http://tor.stackexchange.com/) as well as [Super User](http://superuser.com/). Apparently Tor beta hasn't gotten around to setting up the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, but I'm positive your question is on topic. It's also on topic for Super User since it pertains to software. If your question was about the `Bash` code then it would be on topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: The reason I say to ask on Tor as well as Super User is because Tor is in beta and (probably) has less users than Super User, so your question might get answered faster on Super User. If you do ask on both and one gets answered then just remember to update the other question with a link to the answer.

Comment: @Jonny: Cross-posting the same question on multiple sites is discouraged.